# MLEvaluate() Function Gives Error

Tags: programming, mathlink-or-wstp, c++

I am trying to link my C++ program to Mathematica Kernel. I am trying to use the MLEvaluate() evaluate but I receive an error while compilation. My codes are as below:

```
#include <mathlink.h> //mathlink header
#include <stdio.h> //standard io header
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

/* initialising variables */
MLENV env = (MLENV)0;
MLINK link = (MLINK)0;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int errno;
    int packet;
    int input;

    /* initialises MathLink environemnt object */
    env = MLInitialize(0);

    /* links the program to the MathKernel */
    link = MLOpenString(env, "-linkmode launch -linkname 'C:\\Program Files\\Wolfram Research\\Mathematica\\9.0\\math.exe'", &errno);

        MLEvaluate(link,"2+2+2");

    /* get packets until we find a ReturnPacket or error */
    while ((packet = MLNextPacket(link)) && packet != RETURNPKT) MLNewPacket(link);

    /* once the results is returned */
    if (MLError(link)) printf("\nError Has Occured!\n");    //if an error is returned
    else {                                                      //if an integer is returned
        int result;
        MLGetInteger(link, &result); //we know that the result is an integer in this case
        printf("\nResult: %d\n", result);
}

    printf("\nPress Enter to Exit...");
    getchar(); //holds the console till users presses enter
    getchar(); //holds the console till users presses enter
    return 0;
```

}

the error is get however is:

```
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _MLEvaluate referenced in function _main  C:\Users\arvindrajan\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\MathematicaConsoleApplication\MathematicaConsoleApplication\main.obj MathematicaConsoleApplication
```

any advise?

thanks

Comment: The documentation says, "MLEvaluate() is only available for use in mprep MathLink template programs.".  It sounds like you are calling Mathematica from a C program, not the reverse, so you are not using a template.  This would mean you can't use `MLEvaluate()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a linking error, not a compilation error.

It occurs because the linker can't find `MLEvaluate()`:  the documentation states that

> MLEvaluate() is only available for use in mprep MathLink template programs.

That's because this function is defined in the C source output by [`mprep`](https://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/program/mprep.html) when processing a template files.  Template files apply only when you create an [installable](https://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/InstallableMathLinkPrograms.html) MathLink program that's used from within Mathematica, not when you have a standalone C program that uses Mathematica.

To sum up, you'll need to implement this functionality yourself, without `MLEvaluate()`.  As a starting point, look at the source output by `mprep` for `MLEvaluate`:

```c
int MLEvaluate( MLINK mlp, char* s)
{
    if( MLAbort) return 0;
    return MLPutFunction( mlp, "EvaluatePacket", 1L)
        && MLPutFunction( mlp, "ToExpression", 1L)
        && MLPutString( mlp, s)
        && MLEndPacket( mlp);
} /* MLEvaluate */
```

Comment: Thank you very much. the MLAbort now gives the same problem:

Error 2 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _MLAbort C:\Users\arvindrajan\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\MathematicaConsoleApplication\MathematicaConsoleApplication\main.obj MathematicaConsoleApplication

without MLAbort, it works perfectly fine, just that there is no safety feature

Comment: @arvindrajan92 It seems `MLAbort` is also something you can only use in installable MathLink programs.  I don't have a lot of experience calling Mathematica from standalone C programs.  I've only ever written installable MathLink programs, relying on templates, for serious projects.  So I'd also have to look up the details.  If you're writing a standalone program, it will be helpful to first get familiar with template-based ones and look at the code `mprep` generates.  You can check when and why the variable `MLAbort` is set there.

Comment: It is the [urgent message handler](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/c/MLSetMessageHandler.html) that it setting it when it receives an `MLAbortMessage`.  I *think* this functionality won't be necessary at all if your aim is to call Mathematica from a C program, but not call your C program from Mathematica.  The purpose if this functionality is to allow your C functions, called through MathLink, to be aborted when you try to interrupt a calculation with Alt-. from within Mathematica.